# Creating keystore file from certificate

Tags: authentication, api-client-certificate

I have a .crt file shared with my client but when i converted it into .jks format and try importing it into salesforce under Certificate and Key Management it gives me below error:

> Error: No certificate was imported because the keystore file doesn't contain a PrivateKey entry. Check the file and try again.

Comment: I've only ever moved in the other direction, creating the cert in SF and moving it out. Never had this error. I would ask you to provide the cert but that kind of goes against the whole point of a private key :P My best advise is google for some example certs and check the text of your cert to make sure they match.

Comment: its a third party server's certificate need to used as two way ssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. Your cert is missing vital information. The only thing you'll be able to do is provide the error to the issuer and request a new cert.

If you want to be extra thorough, google some examples of a certificate online and compare them to the text in your cert to make sure they have the same format before you request a new cert. That way, if they tell you you're wrong or give you any grief, you have something to show them.

That can backfire as well though, you may determine that your cert actually does have the correct information and SF is just being picky. In which case, you'll have to open a support ticket.